# All sounds that come out of wine are distorted with buffer underruns

Tags: sound, wine, alsa

I've been having a lot of problems getting any of my applications to work under wine.  I get everything installed fine, the games run great but they all suffer from the same problem.  REALLY REALLY distorted sound!  I've tried going into winecfg and setting the audio settings to ALSA and then setting it to emulation but that doesn't solve anything.  At one point I got half-life to work fine but then in trying to do something else I messed it up, unfortunately I don't remember what that was or what I did to get it working.  There are sounds being made but they come extremely stuttered and unusable.  Please let me know if there's anything I can do to give you more information but I'm pretty sure the problem is from buffer underrun errors.  I don't really know what those are or how to deal with them but I've seen that in debug output most of the time I'm having issues.

Comment: Maybe related or duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/392911/wine-sound-is-played-way-too-fast-and-crackles-horribly

Answer (score 2):

Installing WineTricks solves sound issues a lot of times, also you can install PlayOnLinux.  Both are available in the software center or you could search dotdeb.com for a similar program.

Comment: I've installed winetricks and PlayOnLinux however I'm still having the same issues.  I install the majority of my windows programs through PlayOnLinux but they're all having the same buffer underrun issues.  Is there a specific DLL or something I should install with WineTricks?

Comment: i also use playonlinux and winetricks and still get the crackling / distorted sound. I read that I need to change the buffer size, but I have no idea how to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PulseAudio? It works great here using that. Also make sure you are using wine-1.5. It is available from [the Wine PPA](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Comment: Yes I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 which uses PulseAudio.  I've read in many forums that there's a lot of problems with the way Ubuntu uses PulseAudio and wine.