# The sound on many of my games crackles and sounds distorted

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 64bit with some USB headphones. Many of my steam games are playing with distorted sounds which seem to be a pulseaudio error. I've tried to record an example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLdmMSQNvWA .

I've tried the solutions here: [Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad) and [Wine sound is played way too fast and crackles horribly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392911/wine-sound-is-played-way-too-fast-and-crackles-horribly)
as well as looking through the Arch wiki for a few common troubleshooting tips but with no luck.

Comment: have you found any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I [found an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162398/368930) that worked for me with a similar issue.

Changing `default-fragment-size-msec` to 5 instead of the default 25 in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` (on Ubuntu 16.04, at least) and restarting the PulseAudio daemon helped fix the issue for my needs. Might be worth a shot if you haven't found another solution yet.