# Audacity 2.05 Crashes Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, crash, audacity

Hi Audacity is crashing after a few seconds; the cursor slows down noticeably and it then makes a buzzing noise, I hit stop, screen greys out and I have to force quit. The Audacity log reads;

```
19:53:50: Audacity 2.0.5
19:53:56: Retrieving FFmpeg library version numbers:
19:53:56:    AVCodec version 0x362300 - 54.35.0 (built against 0x362300 - 54.35.0)
19:53:56:    AVFormat version 0x361404 - 54.20.4 (built against 0x361404 - 54.20.4)
19:53:56:    AVUtil version 0x340300 - 52.3.0 (built against 0x340300 - 52.3.0)
```

I started Audacity from terminal; initially I get this;

> (process:3221): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
>
> (process:3221): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
>
> (process:3221): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
>
> (process:3221): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
>   ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
>   ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
>   ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
>   bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>   bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>   bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>   bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>   Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
>   Cannot connect to server request channel
>   jack server is not running or cannot be started
>   Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1736
>   Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1904
>   Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->capture, alsaApi, inParams, StreamDirection_In, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2171
>   Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2840
>   ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave

........{text removed here as it repeats!}.........

> ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
>   Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1736
>   Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1904
>   Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->capture, alsaApi, inParams, StreamDirection_In, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2171
>   Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2840
>   Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
>   Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611

When it crashes I get

> ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

This issue is very similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392911/wine-sound-is-played-way-too-fast-and-crackles-horribly?s=1%7C0.7922) - but I am not running Audacity in Wine.

Soundcard used;

> $ cat /proc/asound/cards
>    0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
>                         HDA Intel at 0xb0000000 irq 40

**UPDATE - the following seems to have worked for now; I checked playback devices and My soundcard was not selected; in Audacity >Edit>preferences.... under devices make sure your soundcard is selected; I hope this has fixed it.**

Comment: Can post Var log - Kern log if it helps

Comment: Try running `audacity` from a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) instead of from the launcher or applications menu. When it crashes, are there any error messages in the terminal window?

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: The other thing I noticed when using Audacity is that it backs up projects to a temporary file. I had limited drive space at that time and it seemed that this was the cause of many audacity issues. Space would get used up - Ubuntu would crash as a result. Deleting the cached files or moving them to a different partition with more space worked